# Making a min heap that holds pair <int, custom class>

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph, priority-queue, shortest-path

I am designing a bipartite graph of Actor and Movie objects that I want to perform djikstra's algorithm on in order to find the shortest path between two Actor objects.

I already have my graph designed and building. Here is my design if you are interested...

actor.h:

```
/* (Vertex) Object Class to represent actors */
 class ActorNode {
         friend class Movie;
         friend class ActorGraph;
     public:
         /*Member Variables*/
         std::string name;
         std::set<Movie*> movies;
         /*Constructor*/
         ActorNode(std::string name) : name(name) {}
         /*Destructor*/
         ~ActorNode();

         /*Getters and Setters*/
         std::string getName();
         void setName(std::string actor);

         /*Member Functions*/

 };
```

movie.h:

```
 class Movie {
     public:
         friend class ActorNode;
         friend class ActorGraph;

         std::string name;
         int year;
         int weight;
         std::set<ActorNode*> cast;
         /*Constructor*/
         Movie(std::string name, int year) : name(name), year(year), weight(1) {}
         /*Destructor*/
         ~Movie();
         /*Getters and Setters*/
         std::string getMovie();
         void setMovie(std::string movie);

         int getYear();
         void setYear(int yr);

         int getWeight();
         void setWeight(int wt);

         /*Member Functions*/
 };
```

ActorGraph.h:

```
  class ActorGraph {
       public:
         unordered_map<std::string,ActorNode*> actorMap;
         unordered_map<std::string,Movie*> movieMap;

         ActorGraph(void);

         bool loadFromFile(const char* in_filename, bool use_weighted_edges);

     };
```

The function loadFromFile reads from a file where each line is an actor and movie they starred in along with it's year.
Just allows me to more easily create a graph from a text file.

Anyways my question is in trying to implement djikstra's with my data structure.

I want to use a priority queue of pair of ints,ActorNode* where the int is going to represent my distance from the source. A priority queue by default is a max_heap but I want to make it a min heap. This is covered in some other topics where this is shown...

```
std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>, std::greater<int> > my_min_heap;
```

so i tried to follow this example for my purposes...

```
std::priority_queue<std::pair<int,ActorNode*>,std::vector<std::pair<int,ActorNode*>,std::greater<int>> min_heap;
```

but it says arguments 2 and 3 of are invalid.
Is there a way to make a priority queue how I want to? Thank you!

*UPDATE*

OK so I have written my comparison class...

```
/* comparison class */
 class pairCompare{
     public:
         typedef std::pair<int, ActorNode*> p;

         struct compare{
             bool operator()(const p& a, const p& b) {
                 if (a.first > b.first) return true;
                 else return false;
             }
         };

     private:
         std::priority_queue<p,std::vector<std::pair<int,ActorNode*>>,pairCompare> pq; };
```

but now getting an incomplete type error...

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/queue:64:0,
                 from movie.h:6,
                 from actor.h:8,
                 from ActorGraph.h:14,
                 from ActorGraph.cpp:15:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_queue.h: In instantiation of ‘class std::priority_queue<std::pair<int, ActorNode*>, std::vector<std::pair<int, ActorNode*> >, pairCompare>’:
ActorGraph.h:61:84:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_queue.h:391:18: error: ‘std::priority_queue<_Tp, _Sequence, _Compare>::comp’ has incomplete type
       _Compare   comp;
```

I researched this and the solution I found was I should forward declare my ActorNode class within my comparison class, but doesn't fix the error. Did I create my comparison class correctly? Trying to have it produce a priority queue that is a min heap.

Other question: Assuming I can get this comparison class working... Do i use the member variable, pq, by creating a comparePairs object? Maybe it would just be easier to create the compare class separate the pq that will be using it. Just seems weird to actually create a comparePairs object vs just making a priority queue and using comparePairs as the 3rd argument for what comparison to use.

Comment: how does this show lack of research? I pasted something from another stack overflow post. I am trying to adapt it to suit me though. People should be able to get penalized for just downvoting without a legit reason

Comment: `std::greater<int>` won't work with `std::pair<int, ActorNode*>`. You'll have to create your own comparison function.

Comment: Also, for what it's worth, it looks like the first downvote was because your question was too long and contained a lot of unnecessary code. It wasn't immediately obvious what the problem was. Questions are a lot easier to understand and answer when they contain the minimum amount of information necessary.

Comment: Fair enough. I've just been down voted in other posts for not providing enough information in the past so usually I try to give too much rather than too little. Like if I just showed what I was trying to do with the priority queue, I feel like I would have gotten "what problem are you trying to solve? give more details." "what is ActorNode?" kinda of questions. Can't please everyone I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line,

```
std::priority_queue<std::pair<int,ActorNode*>,std::vector<std::pair<int,ActorNode*>,std::greater<int>> min_heap;
```

In the second argument,

`std::vector<std::pair<int,ActorNode*>` . You don't close the angle braces. Try this:

```
std::priority_queue<std::pair<int,ActorNode*>,std::vector<std::pair<int,ActorNode*>>,std::greater<int>> min_heap;
```

On a side note, when I used to do Djikstra's or A*, I found that the `std::map` performed way better than the `std::priority_queue`. Could have been an implementation problem on my side though. You may want to check `std::map` if you are concerned about performance.

Comment: Well, you were absolutely correct about my error. Thank you for that! Also though I still believe I need to create my own comparison class. The argument errors are fixed, but the compiler is now saying   '/usr/include/c++/5/bits/predefined_ops.h:123:46: error: no match for call to ‘(std::greater<int>) (std::pair<int, ActorNode*>&, std::pair<int, ActorNode*>&)'. I'll get to work on making a comparison class! thanks everyone!

Comment: @KoalaIsDead : Do mark the answer as correct if it solved your problem.